# What are the trade-offs involved in assigning (or not assigning) helper functions to an object?

Tags: javascript

Here two example JS files that create an object. Lets say the `doSomethingHelper` function is never ever called outside of the `doSomething` function.

Example 1 (helper assigned to object):

```
(function() {
  var myObject = {
    doSomething: function (a) {
      // some code here
      this.doSomethingHelper();
      // maybe more code here
    },

    doSomethingHelper: function () {
      // code here
    }
  }

  return myObject;
})();
```

Example 2 (helper NOT part of the object):

```
(function() {
  var myObject = {
    doSomething: function (a) {
      // some code here
      doSomethingHelper.call(this);
      // maybe more code here
    }
  }

  function doSomethingHelper() {
    // code here
  }

  return myObject;
})();
```

As far as I can tell, the second example can be easier to read at times, and avoids "polluting" the object's namespace. However, it's easier to write tests for the helper function in the first example.

Are there any tradeoffs I'm missing?

Comment: There are minor differences wrt. scoping/accessibility, but mostly just a different way to skip the same rock ..

Comment: If you really need to split it out into another function, make sure you're taking into account things like [the Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). In the second example, you've created an object that has references above it's scope. In some cases that may be appropriate, thanks to the way Javascript is built. If `doSomethingHelper` is only called in `doSomething`, is violating the Law of Demeter appropriate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the objective remains the same, the first one should be the best choice, at least for me. It establishes a contact with the object directly, while the second one does too, but indirectly using `call(this)`, which is used to set the context.

Why bother setting or changing the context, when you can do it *in* the context?

Also, in the first case, the methods are organised and can only be accessed by `myObject.doSomething()` and you can be assured that there won't be any other way of calling the same, however the second function can be called outside  of the object, and your fellow programmers might not know that it shouldn't be called outside the object, but by following the first way, they completely know what it does and what it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a function on an object that is never called outside the object, the first question you must ask yourself is, how many other functions which are on the object need to use it? If only other function is using it, move the function inside the caller and make it an inner function. If multiple functions need it, then it's possible that the helper function is doing something fairly generic and should *probably* be moved out of the object. The code that is most appropriate always depends on the use case.